# Prove a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

I have begun to study some elementary properties of metric space, and I have some problems proving the space shown below is a metric space. The symmetric and positive properties are easy to show, but I can't prove the triangle inequality holds. Any help is welcomed!

$$d(f,g)=\sqrt{\int_{a}^{b} |f(x)-g(x)|^2dx}$$

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality

Comment: Have you ever heard about the Jensen's inequality $\int|f(x)g(x)|dx\le\sqrt{\int|f(x)|^2}dx\sqrt{\int|g(x)|^2}dx$? Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very familiar with Minkowski inequality, but after checking I think it would be applicable if the spare is outside of the integral sign...This form of Jesen'inequality is new for me, but it looks a lot like Holder inequality, I tried squaring inside the integral sign but I can't manage to apply it.